# Setup Production Database on Staging server in Magento 2.4

Tags: magento2, database, sql, system-configuration

I downloaded the production database. Now I want to setup the database on the staging server. So what sanitize process I have to apply on the database before uploading to the staging server.

Answer (score 0):

- sales_flat_order
- sales_flat_order_address
- sales_flat_order_item
- sales_flat_quote
- sales_flat_quote_item
- sales_flat_shipment
- sales_flat_shipment_item
- sales_flat_creditmemo
- sales_flat_creditmemo_item

These tables store data about orders, quotes, shipments, and credit memos. Truncating or removing the entries in these tables will reset the data for these entities on the staging server.